# the usual examples for multi-variable integrals

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

well sadly in our exam our tutor is going to ask us to calculate different integrals etc. Well we're studying maths and not "being a good calculator" but in contrast to give exercises about simple proofs or arguments or counterexamples he's willing to give us an exam like for he applied maths courses -- well anyway we have to deal with this, but hence, we need to kind of get into actual calculating now quite quickly because we were not doing this kind of stuff before a lot and therefore are not quite into it..

Do you know any documents or papers were kind of the usual examples and exercises about integrals, stokes, transformation, substitution for several variables are explained in a simple way to kind of "learn to be a calculator" for the exam quickly :P

Thanks

Comment: Stewart Calculus. Plenty of examples and exercises there.

Comment: try [mit ocw](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/index.htm) , there are problems sets, exams and solutions on each topic